# Cannot generate sql in entity framework for oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, ef-model-first

I am trying to generate oracle sql for my entity framework model.

I can generate the SQLServer sql fine, the error only occurs with oracle generation.

I've installed the oracle developer tools for VS fine.
I have selected "Generate Oracle Via T4 (TPT).xaml (VS)" for the Database Generation Workflow, and "SSDLTOOracle.tt (VS)" for the DDL generation Template.

When I attempt to generate the sql from the right click menu, I get the following error repeated over and over again:

> The SSDL generated by the activity called 'CsdlToSsdlAndMslActivity' is not valid and has the following errors:
>   Default value (false) is not compatible with the facets specified for Decimal. The value must be a decimal number with scale less than or equal to 38  and precision less than or equal to 38.
>   ... [snip]

My model does not contain any Decimals.
I tried setting the default value of my Int32's and Double's to something other than `(None)`, but that did not fix it.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework and odp.net do you use?

Comment: @BootStrapper all my pacakges are latest from nuget - EF 6.1.3, ODP.NET Managed 12.1.022, ODP.NET Managed EF 12.1.022

Answer (score 0):

Can you add that xml definition to your project's app/web.config file (inside of "configuration" section), and then try again.

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
  <settings>
    <add name="bool" value="edmmapping number(1,0)" />
    <add name="byte" value="edmmapping number(3,0)" />
    <add name="int16" value="edmmapping number(5,0)" />
    <add name="int32" value="edmmapping number(10,0)" />
    <add name="int64" value="edmmapping number(19,0)" />
    <add name="int16" value="edmmapping number(38,0)" />
    <add name="int32" value="edmmapping number(38,0)" />
    <add name="int64" value="edmmapping number(38,0)" />
  </settings>
</oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

Comment: I'm using the managed driver, so instead I tried   ``<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <edmMappings>
      <edmMapping dataType="number">
        <add name="bool" precision="1"/>
        <add name="byte" precision="3" />
        <add name="int16" precision="5" />
        <add name="int32" precision="10" />
        <add name="int64" precision="19" />
        <add name="int16" precision="38" />
        <add name="int32" precision="38" />
        <add name="int64" precision="38" />
      </edmMapping>
    </edmMappings>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>``

Comment: This did not work though,  I still get the same message when attempting to generate the model

Comment: OK. Could you try with "SSDLToSQL10.tt" option (keep the config changes)?

Comment: I tried every combination of the three Database Generation Workflows, with the two DDL Generation Templates and all of them gave me the same error.